# [Typeorm]: Optimizing Nested Relational Loading

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have an entity called "recipes" which is related to its sub-recipes through an entity called "RecipeSubrecipeEntity." When retrieving recipe data, I use the FindOptionsRelations to specify which related entities to load. However, I'm facing an issue when a sub-recipe has its own sub-recipes, and so on. I find it challenging to load more than a certain level of nesting using the FindOptionsRelations. I'm looking for a way to load all levels of nesting without explicitly stating each level in the FindOptionsRelations. Is there a more efficient and dynamic approach to achieve this?

```
class RecipeEntity {
  @OneToMany(() => RecipeIngredientEntity, (ingredient) => ingredient.recipe, {
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove'],
  })
  ingredients: RecipeIngredientEntity[];

  @OneToMany(() => RecipeSubrecipeEntity, (subrecipe) => subrecipe.recipe, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove'],
  })
  subrecipes: RecipeSubrecipeEntity[];
}

class RecipeSubrecipeEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'uuid' })
  recipeId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => RecipeEntity, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove'],
  })
  recipe: RecipeEntity;

  @Column({ type: 'uuid' })
  subrecipeId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => RecipeEntity, (subrecipe) => subrecipe.subrecipes, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove'],
  })
  subrecipe: RecipeEntity;

  @Column({ type: 'float4', default: 1 })
  quantity: number;
}

const recipeRelationOptions: FindOptionsRelations<RecipeEntity> = {
  subrecipes: {
    subrecipe: {
      ingredients: {
        ingredient: {
          unitOfMeasure: true,
        },
      },
      subrecipes: {
        subrecipe: {
          ingredients: {
            ingredient: {
              unitOfMeasure: true,
            },
          },
          subrecipes: {
            subrecipe: {
              ingredients: {
                ingredient: {
                  unitOfMeasure: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```